# WiiRemoteJ Sound Issue (wiimote speaker)

Tags: java, wiimote

I was wondering if anyone can help, I'm using the [WiiRemoteJ](http://www.world-of-cha0s.hostrocket.com/WiiRemoteJ/) Java library for connecting to a Wiimote (Wii Remote).  I have the supplied WRLIpml test application up and running but I'm having some problems with the sound being sent to the wiimotes speaker.

I'm using the sample sound file provided with the library, but instead of playing a recognizable tune when it's supposed to play, the Wiimote is playing a very quiet ticking noise.

I can see that the sound file supplied is being found correctly because when I run it through the debugger, it works fine.

I'm using the built in Mac OSX Bluetooth Stack and Bluecove.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Still haven't managed to resolve this but I did contact Michael Diamond who wrote the WiiRemoteJ library.  His suggestions were that usually this is caused by a low-power issue or a distance issue.  Neither of which are the problem in my case but thought I would mention it in case it helps anyone else.